# How to safely detect users with no authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, networking

I'm looking for solutions, or workarounds, for detecting users accessing my website from within a company network **without the need of a user/password login**. These users have some unrestricted access to my site.

Came to my mind to check the user's IP against a known IP range or subnetwork, but this does not seems to be the most reliable or secure solution.

Comment: A company network should have its characteristics you can learn from its network administrators. For instance, they might issue internal certificates to all users for client certificate authentication, which you might also use. So it is too broad to discuss here, as nobody here knows their network setup.

Comment: Thank you Lex for your words. I'd also love my clients have this kind of certifications for an easy identifcation. Sadly, I dare to say, none of them have :( Maybe another method not so spoofable like the IP might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We when say `safely detect the users` ,it means we are authenticating the users in  way and then `without the need of user/password login` makes it tricky.But we can acheive this

> All you have to do is enable windows authentication for your website
>   in IIS.

If we configure windows authentication correctly,you will get following

- if the website is browsed using IE, mostly the login will be transparent as there will not be any authentication prompt
- For firefox/crhome,if i remember correctly,there is a flag to enable to make automatic kerberos login in firefox and chrome should automatically login .

[image: enable windows auth in IIS]

Normally the windows login prompt works perfectly fine with IE (some settings are needed but those settings can be controlled using domian policies). In case you still get auth prompts ,you just want some kind of authentication,you can have NTLM enabled and no kerberos in IIS settings

If you still get authentication prompt,try enabling just NTLM and check

IIS ->Website->Authentication->Windows Authentication->Providers remove negotiate

[image: remove negotiate from providers]

For some reason user cannot be authenticated(user comes from different domain or forest),then an authentication prompt is shown.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Didn't remember the Kerberos option so gonna give it a shot :)